# Feature engineering using the target/dependent variable

Tags: feature-engineering, fraud-detection

I am a beginner and my question relates to feature engineering. My task is to help develop a model which predicts whether a customer request is a fraud case.

A variable in the dataset is the applicant's zip code. Is it ok to create an indicator variable which is 0 if fraud does not happen frequently (e.g. <2% fraud) for this postal code and 1 otherwise? 
Or is this wrong because I would use the dependent variable (isFraud) to find out in which places fraud happens frequently and falsify the result?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually incorporating some kind of *prior* information into your dataset, which is perfectly OK if you don't include use your test and validation sets while calculating these statistics. Otherwise, you leak information, and your test results become (maybe overly) optimistic. So, you'll calculate these zip code statistics based on your training set, and label your test set accordingly.